# Chart.js fields not showing characters correctly

Tags: utf-8, chart.js

When using the `config` code shown below the title is with error shown at the image. This also occurs at other fields such as tooltip and labels.

But when I tried it at https://codepen.io/ I've a got a correct result (title as expected).

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

```
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: dataSource,
        options: {
            plugins: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Código',
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

[image: Error sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve this, first include at `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
</system.web>
```

Then check each JS and HTML files for the correct encoding. With `Notepad++`, open each JS/HTML file (via Windows, outside Visual Studio) and check file encoding, expected is `UTF-8 BOM`. I've had several files with `ANSI` format. To change, `Notepad++` has a builtin tool available at the menu, then you just save the updated file.

[image: Notepad++ file encoding]

Finally, open Visual Studio and those changes should appear automatically and you can upload/commit them to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `ó` by its HexCode as follows.

```
title: {
  display: true,
  text: 'C' + '\xF3' + 'digo'
}
```

or...

```
title: {
  display: true,
  text: 'Código'.replace('ó', '\xF3')
}
```

Comment: While this may work for the fixed names (titles) it will not work for labels and tooltips, since they are filled with several types of special characters